# Как изменить положение кучи во время исполнения программы?

Tags: c, ассемблер, компоновщик, stm32

Здравствуйте.
Я использую stm32f429, пишу на keil, начальную настройку делаю через CubeMX.
Мне необходимо сразу после инициализации SDRAM перенести туда кучу моей программы.

Нашёл в интернете такой код

```
void dummy_function1(void)
{
    __asm
    {
        EXPORT __heap_base
        __heap_base EQU 0xD0400000  
        EXPORT __heap_limit
        __heap_limit EQU 0x400000 
    }
}
```

Но компилятор не собирает его, выводя вот такие ошибки

../Src/main.c(227): error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
                EXPORT __heap_base
../Src/main.c(228): error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
                __heap_base EQU 0xD0400000
../Src/main.c(229): error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
                EXPORT __heap_limit
../Src/main.c(230): error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
                __heap_limit EQU 0x400000

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить положение кучи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашему ассемблерному коду - скорее всего, имелось в виду `EXTERN`, а не `EXPORT`. А переменные `__heap_base` и `__heap_limit` объявлены в скрипте линкера. Посмотрите, действительно ли они именно так называются.

А вообще, если этот код сработает, то его надо размещать в самом начале работы программы (то есть в `ResetHandler`, до вызова `main`). Только тогда у вас может что-то получиться. После того, как вся память данных (heap, stack, bss) инициализирована, вряд ли у вас получится изменить её. Но, судя по вашему предыдущему вопросу, вы используете `freeRTOS`, и, скорее всего, менеджер памяти этой операционной системы: `pvPortMalloc` и `vPortFree`. Эта система в качестве кучи берёт большой массив из статической памяти, и в дальнейшем выделяет куски из этого массива, когда вы пользуетесь механизмом выделения и освобождения памяти.

Попробуйте исследовать freeRTOS_CONFIG.h и найти там размер и расположение его кучи. В найденных макроопределениях вместо целых чисел укажите свою функцию, которая вернула бы правильное расположение кучи. Но учтите, что вам нужно либо не пользоваться кучей до её переноса, либо позаботиться о копировании всей кучи в новое место, обновив при этом все указатели на неё.

---

UPD. А если не мудрить, то я бы сразу в скрипте линкера прописал, что куча должна располагаться в SDRAM и не пользовался бы ей до того, как инициализировал FMC.

Comment: Если я настраиваю FMC в main, и не вызываю функций динамического распределения памяти(malloc например) до настройки FMC, то куча не используется(если считать что код инициализации написан полностью мной)?

Comment: Код инициализации - имеете в виду настройку FMC или инициализацию bss в `ResetHandler`? Если вы не трогали стартовый код, то нельзя быть полностью в этом уверенным. Думаю, вам лучше будет исследовать код в `ResetHandler`, который расположен в `startup_stm32fXXXX.s`. Там вы и найдёте точный ответ на свой вопрос. Маловероятно, но всё же если куча там будет использоваться, то вам придётся код настройки FMC располагать в `ResetHandler`.

Comment: Как работают функции tasks в freeRTOS. Вернее откуда они берут память для работы. Обычная функция все свои переменные хранит в стеке. А freeRTOS создаёт свою версию стека и там всё находится? Или при вызове такс перезаписывает себя в стек основной?

Comment: @kvazik, freeRTOS создаёт свой стек для каждой задачи. Но из какой памяти - не знаю. Очевидно, что эту память тоже нужно перенести в SDRAM.